# dynamically populate column name in Python dataframe join

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I am developing a dynamic script which can `join` any given pyspark dataframes. The problem is the column names in file will vary & number of join conditions may vary. I can handle this in a loop but I execute the join with a variable name it fails.

*(My intention is to dynamically populate a and b or more columns based on file structure and join conditions)*

```
b="incrementalFile.Id1"
a="existingFile.Id"
unChangedRecords = existingFile.join(incrementalFile,(a==b),"left")
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in    File
>   "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 818, in join
>           assert isinstance(on[0], Column), "on should be Column or list of Column" AssertionError: on should be Column or list of Column

But the same code works fine if I don't place any variables in `join` condition as below.

```
unChangedRecords = existingFile.join(
    incrementalFile,
    (existingFile.Id==incrementalFile.Id1), 
    "left")
```

Comment: Why is this tagged 'scala'?

Comment: @DyZ : the reason is, the logic can be same in scala or pyspark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example, `existingFile.Id` is a column, not a string, but in your first example, it's a string. You want to use [pyspark.sql.functions.col](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.col) to reference the column by name. Its docs don't have an example, but it's used in the example for [alias](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.alias) on the same page.

Comment: you are great ! thats a good catch. Let me try and accept the answer.. +1 for now